# Pandas, merge multiple dummy variables into one column by name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, dummy-variable

I have a datafile with one VALUE column and multiple dummy variables representing TYPES. I have copied a short example below. I need the average of each type (which I can get) with a column with the named type (which I don't seem to be able to get). Pointers would be welcome.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'salary' : [50000, 45000, 55000, 40000, 35000, 45000, 30000,25000,35000],
        'manager': [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0], 'foreman': [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0], 
        'worker': [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df
```

This is my input data.

```
salary  manager foreman worker
0   50000   1   0   0
1   45000   1   0   0
2   55000   1   0   0
3   40000   0   1   0
4   35000   0   1   0
5   45000   0   1   0
6   30000   0   0   1
7   25000   0   0   1
8   35000   0   0   1
```

I can get the average, like this, but not consolidate the three dummy vars into one categorical column:

```
print(df.groupby(['manager','foreman','worker']).mean().reset_index())

manager  foreman  worker  salary
0        0        0       1   30000
1        0        1       0   40000
2        1        0       0   50000
```

I would like to have something that looks like this:

```
need = {'salary' : [50000, 45000, 55000, 40000, 35000, 45000, 30000,25000,35000],
        'type': ['manager','manager','manager','foreman','foreman','foreman','worker','worker','worker']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=need)
df2

salary  type
0   50000   manager
1   45000   manager
2   55000   manager
3   40000   foreman
4   35000   foreman
5   45000   foreman
6   30000   worker
7   25000   worker
8   35000   worker
```

I can do this simple example by hand. The result looks like this, which is ultimately where I will end up:

```
pay = {'type' : ['manager','foreman','worker'], 'avg_pay': [50000,40000,30000]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=pay)
df1

type    avg_pay
0   manager 50000
1   foreman 40000
2   worker  30000
```

Can't seem to find any documentation on how to "undummy" variables. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solutions if always only one `1` per row:

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with `ignore_index=False` and `var_name='type'` parameter, last filter by `1` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for remove column `value`:

```
df = (df.melt('salary', ignore_index=False, var_name='type')
        .loc[lambda x: x.pop('value').eq(1)])
print (df)
   salary     type
0   50000  manager
1   45000  manager
2   55000  manager
3   40000  foreman
4   35000  foreman
5   45000  foreman
6   30000   worker
7   25000   worker
8   35000   worker
```

Or:

```
s = df.drop('salary', axis=1).stack()
df = df[['salary']].join(s[s.eq(1)].index.to_frame().droplevel(1)[1].rename('type'))
print (df)
   salary     type
0   50000  manager
1   45000  manager
2   55000  manager
3   40000  foreman
4   35000  foreman
5   45000  foreman
6   30000   worker
7   25000   worker
8   35000   worker
```

Solution if possible multiple `1` per rows with [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) by columns names for separate values by `,`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('salary')
df = df1.eq(1).dot(df1.columns + ',').str[:-1].reset_index(name='type')
print (df)
   salary     type
0   50000  manager
1   45000  manager
2   55000  manager
3   40000  foreman
4   35000  foreman
5   45000  foreman
6   30000   worker
7   25000   worker
8   35000   worker
```

Testing data with multiple `1`:

```
data = {'salary' : [50000, 45000, 55000, 40000, 35000, 45000, 30000,25000,35000],
        'manager': [1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0], 'foreman': [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0], 
        'worker': [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print (df)
   salary  manager  foreman  worker
0   50000        1        0       1
1   45000        1        0       0
2   55000        1        0       0
3   40000        0        1       1
4   35000        1        1       0
5   45000        0        1       0
6   30000        0        0       1
7   25000        0        0       1
8   35000        0        0       1

df1 = df.set_index('salary')
df = df1.eq(1).dot(df1.columns + ',').str[:-1].reset_index(name='type')
print (df)
   salary             type
0   50000   manager,worker
1   45000          manager
2   55000          manager
3   40000   foreman,worker
4   35000  manager,foreman
5   45000          foreman
6   30000           worker
7   25000           worker
8   35000           worker
```

Comment: Hello jezrael, may I ask whether it is possible to perform 2 statements in one single `pipe` call?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR - Why not try it? For me working `.pipe(lambda d: d.loc[d['value'].eq(1)].drop('value', axis=1))`

Answer (score 3):

If you always have a maximum of one 1 per row, pandas 1.5 introduced the [`pandas.from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html#pandas.from_dummies) function:

```
df[['salary']].join(pd.from_dummies(df.drop(columns='salary'))[''].rename('type'))

# or
pd.DataFrame({'salary': df['salary'],
              'type': pd.from_dummies(df.drop(columns='salary'))['']})
```

*NB. if one of the rows can have only 0s, add the `default_category=np.nan` parameter to `from_dummies`.*

Output:

```
   salary     type
0   50000  manager
1   45000  manager
2   55000  manager
3   40000  foreman
4   35000  foreman
5   45000  foreman
6   30000   worker
7   25000   worker
8   35000   worker
```

Comment: Hello mozway, may I ask what `['']` does here? does it turn a DataFrame into a Series? There is always a nice, subtle point in your solution :)

Comment: @Anoushiravan `from_dummies` can handle a separator to generate several columns. I guess it was decided to always return a DataFrame for consistency, so by default the output is a DataFrame with a single column named `''`.

Comment: Yes it's very interesting. Now I checked `pd.from_dummies(df.drop('salary', axis=1)).columns` I got the point. Thank you very much for the guidance as always.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) for this purpose. Special thanks to [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) for inspiration we can make the code more concise:

```
(df.melt(id_vars='salary', var_name='type')
 .pipe(lambda d: d.loc[d['value'].eq(1)].drop('value', axis=1)))

    salary     type
0    50000  manager
1    45000  manager
2    55000  manager
12   40000  foreman
13   35000  foreman
14   45000  foreman
24   30000   worker
25   25000   worker
26   35000   worker
```